# getting values outof a loop (Clojure)

Tags: loops, clojure

If i make a loop how is it possible to get the values of a variable in standard out by each turn? I am not talking about printing them on the screen, because as long as you are in a loop the values are going back to proceed the loop and not coming out, the only one coming to the standard out is actually the closing value. As an example: `(loop [x 0] (if (< x 5) (recur (inc x)) 1234567890)))` so i only get the 1234567890 as soon as the loop ends, but i want also 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 to the std.out.

Comment: The problem described as-is looks weird and dirty. What is the real problem behind it?

Comment: What do you mean by standard out but not printing? What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: i want to send the values coming from the loop to another function, so i want them to be index numbers for looking up values of  a coll: `(nth (here numbers coming from the loop as index for the next coll) coll`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `loop` is not a loop but a recursion point. If you want to collect all the values you can use some kind of accumulator:

```
(loop [x 0 acc []]
  (if (< x 5)
    (recur (inc x) (conj acc x))
    (conj acc 1234567890)))
```

Unless recursion is what you really want some kind of `map` or `for` (list comprehension) is probably a better choice.

Comment: well the problem is that most of these objects return nil, is it possible to get the values coming from the loop as return value?

Comment: You can for example wrap it using map:  `(conj acc {:v x})`. Still, a whole idea smells fishy. Any particular reason you want to use `loop`?

Comment: Without more details I can only repeat what I've said before - map or for is probably a better choice.

Comment: What i actually want to do is something like (i know this one is not working):
`(nth [1 2 3 4]
     (do (Thread/sleep 500)(for [i (range 4)]
       i)))` so the recursion gives me the content of the collection one by one half a second each.

Comment: The expected output is: `1 2 3 4` between each 500 ms time

Comment: `(map #(nth [1 2 3 4] %) (range 4))` or `(for [i (range 4)] (nth [1 2 3 4] i))`?

Comment: Almost, here you get all the numbers at once to the output, what if you would like to get each next number after a certain time (like 500 ms)?

Comment: For something like this you should take a look at the [core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83585/discussion-between-zero323-and-teymuri).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a list comprehension `for` is what you are looking for, or `range`.
For the `loop` as @zero323 has mentioned you need to use an accumulator.